# How to change the value of the widget argument in KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How do I change the widget argument at the click of a button? That is for example there is a button

```
MDRaisedButton:
        id: but
        pos: (150,150)
        text: 'Старый текст'
        on_press: app.func()
```

How can I replace the text argument with, for example, 'New text' by clicking the same button? What do I need to write in the func function to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MDRaisedButton:
    id: but
    pos: (150,150)
    text: 'Старый текст'
    on_press: app.func(self)


def func(self, instance_button):
    instance_button.text = "New text"
```

Comment: Thank you very much from Russia! Стоп у тебя описание русское, для кого я тут пишу на английском